# how can I add tracking meta information to jpg files?

Tags: security, jpeg, tracking

I have a client that wants to be able to find their proprietary images other places on the internet if someone steals them.

Is there a way to add meta information that we can track for this purpose inside a jpg file?

Comment: Watermarking, text comments within the JPEG standard itself, embedded overlays ... take your pick.  Or just have them go to Google Images and search by the image.  It will show the websites that have exact matches.  But this is a bit of a "shopping" question, so it will likely be closed / put on hold.

Comment: I just don't know what's available. What you mentioned helps because I didn't know what to search for or ask about. I understand it's not as specific a question as I would like either, but I have to start somewhere. I figured I would start on the best Q&A forum available :)

Comment: Yeah, there's the comment "marker" in the JPEG standard.  A watermark involves altering the image.  The "embedded overlays" -- I actually made up that term on the fly :) but what I was going for is that it might be possible to encode stuff in the image data that wasn't readily visible or easily strippable the way a comment is.

Comment: That specifically, embedded overlays concept, is what I want to find out more about.

Comment: you can add an entry in EXIF IFD(metadata in binary) of jpeg image. It is not visible in image as it is. There are many EXIF editor/reader tools which will allow you to edit/read it. for example you can add a particular string in makernote of jpeg. As I said, there are tools available in market, this also means that people can edit also reset the complete EXIF metadata which will erase your data too.

Answer (score 0):

My answer was getting too long for comment so posting it as answer.

you can add an entry in EXIF IFD(metadata in binary) of jpeg image. It is not visible in image as it is. There are many EXIF editor/reader tools which will allow you to edit/read it. for example you can add a particular string in makernote of jpeg.

As I said, there are tools available in market, this also means that people can edit also reset the complete EXIF metadata which will erase your data too....

To get around this you can add your copyrighted IFD entry which only you can understand. For this you have to edit some EXIF tool and tweak according to your need.

But while adding your entry in JPEG metadata please take care that you adhere to EXIF/TIFF specifications so that image is not corrupted and readable in all platforms.

Here are some links to help you understand EXIF/TIFF - 
http://gvsoft.homedns.org/exif/exif-explanation.html
and
http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF